# nodemanager error in yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

**I have 100 nodemanagers in my cluster,with 1000 cores and 4.8T Mem.**
**but, some thing driver me crazy on nodemanager recently,and it occurrence once in a while, not every day.**

In Cloudera Management,the health test show me that "GC Duration Unknown" and "Web Server Status Bad":
[image]

Then,my application in cluster will be error with timeout or thread interrupt.

**and nodemanager errorlog is like below:**

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Interrupted: action=RetryAction(action=RETRY, delayMillis=1000, reason=null), retry policy=RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS); Host Details : local host is: "lfh-R720-20/10.1.0.20"; destination host is: "lfh-R720-20":8040; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.heartbeat(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.api.impl.pb.client.LocalizationProtocolPBClientImpl.heartbeat(LocalizationProtocolPBClientImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer.localizeFiles(ContainerLocalizer.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer.runLocalization(ContainerLocalizer.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.startLocalizer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService$LocalizerRunner.run(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1132)
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Interrupted: action=RetryAction(action=RETRY, delayMillis=1000, reason=null), retry policy=RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleConnectionFailure(Client.java:855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleConnectionFailure(Client.java:853)
    ... 13 more
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Interrupted: action=RetryAction(action=RETRY, delayMillis=1000, reason=null), retry policy=RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS); Host Details : local host is: "lfh-R720-20/10.1.0.20"; destination host is: "lfh-R720-20":8040; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.heartbeat(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.api.impl.pb.client.LocalizationProtocolPBClientImpl.heartbeat(LocalizationProtocolPBClientImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer.localizeFiles(ContainerLocalizer.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer.runLocalization(ContainerLocalizer.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.startLocalizer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService$LocalizerRunner.run(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1132)
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Interrupted: action=RetryAction(action=RETRY, delayMillis=1000, reason=null), retry policy=RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleConnectionFailure(Client.java:855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleConnectionFailure(Client.java:853)
    ... 13 more
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Interrupted: action=RetryAction(action=RETRY, delayMillis=1000, reason=null), retry policy=RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS); Host Details : local host is: "lfh-R720-20/10.1.0.20"; destination host is: "lfh-R720-20":8040; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.heartbeat(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.api.impl.pb.client.LocalizationProtocolPBClientImpl.heartbeat(LocalizationProtocolPBClientImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer.localizeFiles(ContainerLocalizer.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer.runLocalization(ContainerLocalizer.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.startLocalizer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService$LocalizerRunner.run(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1132)
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Interrupted: action=RetryAction(action=RETRY, delayMillis=1000, reason=null), retry policy=RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleConnectionFailure(Client.java:855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleConnectionFailure(Client.java:853)
    ... 13 more
```

thank you!

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: yes I will show more description above.